# Error in stored procedure SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I want insert data with bulk insert, a csv file and a Stored procedure, 
my problem is when I use a parameter instead of the path of the csv file, when I change the path for the parameter I get the next error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure carga_masiva, Line 7 [Batch
>   Start Line 7] Incorrect syntax near '@ruta'. Msg 319, Level 15, State
>   1, Procedure carga_masiva, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 7] Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table
>   expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context
>   clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

This is my stored procedure:

```
USE [prueba]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[carga_masiva]
--Parametros que utilizara el procedimiento almacenado
    @ruta nvarchar(250)
AS
--Query que realizara el procedimiento almacenado
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BULK INSERT USUARIO
    FROM @ruta 
    WITH 
    ( 
      FIELDTERMINATOR= ';', 
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
     )
```

Comment: add a semicolon just before WITH, i.e. change WITH to ;WITH. That should help.

Comment: @DEEPAKLAKHOTIA it wouldn't - it would break the statement and the with is needed for the bulk insert. You need to break it if its a CTE. The issues looks to be with from statement

Comment: the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this should work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[carga_masiva] @ruta nvarchar(250) AS
DECLARE @bulkinsert NVARCHAR(2000), @filepath nvarchar(500)
SET @filepath = @ruta
SET
  NOCOUNT ON;

SET @bulkinsert = 
       N'BULK INSERT USUARIO FROM ''' + 
       @filepath + 
       N''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'


EXEC sp_executesql @bulkinsert
```

You could consider building up your BULK INSERT statement as a string  and then execute it as dynamic SQL.

Comment: thanks for your answers I will try with your examples and update the state of the question

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be round where you are inserting from as it is expecting a location as a string e.g. 'C:\Doc' rather than C:\Doc.

Dynamic SQL would be an option e.g.

```
USE [prueba];
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[carga_masiva]
--Parametros que utilizara el procedimiento almacenado
@ruta NVARCHAR(250)
AS
--Query que realizara el procedimiento almacenado
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1024);
     SET @SQL = '

    BULK INSERT USUARIO
    FROM '+CHAR(39)+@ruta+CHAR(39)+'
    WITH 
    ( 
      FIELDTERMINATOR= '';'', 
      ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
     )
';
     EXEC sp_executesql
          @SQL;
```

Pinal Dave has a handy post here : https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

The MS Docs are here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017